# How to randomly combine (concatenate) text in cellsin two columns

Tags: spreadsheet, libreoffice, calc

I want to combine text in multiple cells in one column with text in multiple cells in another column in two columns and have the combinations with permutation (the combination should have the text  from  first column first and second column second in the combined text/result, i.e. only ad, ae, af, bd............. **and not** *da, ea* etc.) in a third column.

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | d | ad |
| b | e | ae |
| c | f | af |
|  |  | bd |
|  |  | be |
|  |  | bf |
|  |  | cd |
|  |  | ce |
|  |  | cf |
|  |  |  |

Preferably there should be no repetition.

If there is a way to randomly create the results (resulting text) in the third column such that both  results  (the combination **can** have the text  from  first column first and second column second in the combined text/result **and also** first text second from first column and second text from the first column, i.e. all combinations ad, *da*, ae, *ea*, af, *fa*, bd, *db*, ......), that would also be nice to know.

I researched online and searched the libreoffice menu. Two items **combin** and **permut** seemed promising, but documentation are lacking as to how to use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, in Calc, this is very simple - you only need two steps.

First, write down the formula of the form

```
{=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10);1;A2:A4&TRANSPOSE(B2:B4);B2:B4&TRANSPOSE(A2:A4))}
```

(this is an array formula, complete the formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**!)

Now select the cell with the result of the formula and choose [**Data - Text to Columns**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.4/en-US/text/shared/00/00000208.html) from the menu.

[image: Cartesian product in Calc]

Comment: This is a nice solution, up-vote from me. However, it replaces the formula with the resulting first text, so that any change in the input cells do not propagate.

Comment: Thank you very much. It had been extremely helpful to me, I am a complete novice. Is there a way of not having da,
db,
dc,
ea,
eb,
ec,
fa,
fb,
fc in the result column

Comment: @thebusybee Yes, you are right, this method gives a static result, in case of changing the initial values, these two steps will need to be repeated. On the other hand, the question did not state the condition for dynamically changing the result, did it?

Comment: @banuyayi I was hoping that you would not just watch the animation, but learn and understand the formula used. In this case, you could change this to get whatever you want (hint: formula should be shorter for fewer results). Since you have not dealt with the formula, then for you the procedure will also include the third step - to clear half of the resulting set of cells. These are the conditions for using StackOverflow - the questioner must definitely do something on his own.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your hint worked perfectly. Kindly continue to guide and teach. You are an adept user. Your suggestions and answers are always helpful.